# ASP.NET 5, EF 7 and SQLite - SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Blog'

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I followed the [Getting Started on ASP.NET 5](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5.html) guide about Entity Framework 7 and I replaced MicrosoftSqlServer with Sqlite, the only difference in the code is in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlite()
    .AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Filename=db.db"));
```

When I run the website and navigate to /Blogs, I get an error:

> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException was unhandled by user code
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259   HResult=-2147467259   Message=SQLite Error 1:
>   'no such table: Blog'   Source=Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
>   SqliteErrorCode=1   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.MarshalEx.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc,
>   Sqlite3Handle db)
>          at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>          at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__1`2.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>          at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at EFGetStarted.AspNet5.Controllers.BlogsController.Index() in d:\arthur\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\EFGetStarted.AspNet5\src\EFGetStarted.AspNet5\Controllers\BlogsController.cs:regel
>   18   InnerException:

I understand this as if there is no table called 'Blog', but when I open the .db file in DB Browser for SQLite, there actually is a table called 'Blog':

[image: Screenshot from DB Browser for SQLite showing a table called 'Blog']

Does SQLite require other changes in the code, or is this an error in the SQLite connector for Entity Framework?

Comment: What does your `BlogsController.Index` method look like?

Comment: do you connect to the right database?

Comment: @DavidG `public IActionResult Index() { return View(_context.Blogs.ToList()); }`

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Isn't that something EF handles? There's just one place in the whole program where info about the location of the database is given. That info is used by EF to create the db, and it should also be used to connect to it, not?

Comment: most likely yes. do you connect to the same with db browser?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro After the first migration application, a db.db file, named as told with the `"Filename=db.db"` connection string, appears in the project root. That's the file I connected to with db browser.

Comment: http://damienbod.com/2015/08/30/asp-net-5-with-sqlite-and-entity-framework-7/

Comment: Call `context.Database.OpenConnection()` then check `context.Database.GetDbConnection().DataSource` to see what file EF is using.

Comment: This is misleading. The Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.MarshalEx.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, Sqlite3Handle db) throws 100% of the time. Please read from SqliteConnection.cs the following member function:public override void Open() . Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is very likely the database actually being opened by EF is not the file you are opening in DB Browser. SQLite use the process current working directory, which if launched in IIS or other servers, can be a different folder than your source code directory. (See issues https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/132 and https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/55).

To ensure your db file is in the right place, use an absolute path. Example:

```
public class Startup
{
    private IApplicationEnvironment _appEnv;

    public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        _appEnv = appEnv;
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlite()
            .AddDbContext<MyContext>(
                options => { options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={_appEnv.ApplicationBasePath}/data.db"); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this answer. I ran into this using ASP.NET Core 1.0. I had my data source specified in appsettings.json and it didn't seem to like the variable so I supplied a hard-coded path like this:   "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=C:\\aspnetcoresqllitedbs\\data\\WebApplication.db"
  }

Comment: Also make sure - especially if you work in cross platform environment like me - that you use unix, or windows file path conventions. While on Windows your program may well read paths with both: "\\" such as "/"  , on Linux "\\" will likely fail to read your file. And the error message from EF Core is just misleading :)

Comment: @SoldOut Your comment on cross platform environment was the cause of my problem. Changing from "Data Source=Data\\coursedb.sqlite" to "Data Source=Data/coursedb.sqlite" on my Mac fixed the issue for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 33):

I did this and was still having trouble loading the database.  I added the following code in the constructor for the database context:
`Database.EnsureCreated();`

---

Now my context file looks like this: [image: BoardGameDBContextFile]

It created a new database on my new Azure hosting site, so if you have a lot of existing data to migrate, this won't work.  It worked for me so figured I'd share.

Comment: Wow, this was exactly my problem as well. I couldn't figure out why EF Core docs were saying my seed data would be populated, the seed data functions were running, and then any queries afterward would always throw a table does not exist exception! Thank you!!

Comment: I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=visual-studio and this solution "Database.EnsureCreated();" provided by @Michael to get rid of this error. Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 16):

Taken from EF Core documentation...

**Run from Visual Studio**

> To run this sample from Visual Studio, you must set the working
>   directory manually to be the root of the project. Ifyou don't set the
>   working directory, the following Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException
>   is thrown: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Blogs'.

To set the working directory:

- In **Solution Explorer**, right click the project and then select **Properties**.
- Select the **Debug** tab in the left pane.
- Set  **Working  directory**  to  the  project  directory.
- Save  the  changes.

Comment: By reading your answer @jjoselon I was able to figure out my own problem, so I am writing this comment if someone else is in the position as me.

I am using asp.net core 3.1, entity framework core on Mac.I have 3 sub projects under the main one and the SQLite Error appeared every time I tried to insert some data into my table(even though the table existed).
In order to fix that right click on the sub project I was running, Run with -> custom configuration and in the field run in directory choose the directory of the corresponding project.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: @jjoselon Your suggestion resolved my issue that I spent two days on (thank you). I was using `EF Core` with startup project of `.NET 4.8`,  `.NET Standard Library 2.0` project with `SQLite`. And, the startup project was not finding the `SQLite` db. Could you please provide a link to the EF Core documentation that you quoted in your solution above?

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue on `netcoreapp2.0`. There's a related [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9560) that may be at fault, but I didn't want to solve it by going to a nightly build.

The solution for me was to create and pass an `SqliteConnection` instead of using the builder string.

So for this setup:

```
string id = string.Format("{0}.db", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

var builder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    DataSource = id,
    Mode = SqliteOpenMode.Memory,
    Cache = SqliteCacheMode.Shared
};
```

Compose for the DI like so:

```
var connection = new SqliteConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
connection.EnableExtensions(true);
services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(connection));
```

The error I had was using this style of init:

```
services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(builder.ConnectionString));
```

My scaffolding also has a one-time call to:

```
var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SomeDbContext>();
dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Using this approach all my DI-instantiated copies of `SomeDbContext` would all point at a valid SQLite db, and that db would have auto-created schema as per my entities.

Comment: The last snippet is the actual key to this problem in my case. The SQLite connection behaves differently than the others I've used.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like things have changed because IApplicationEnvironment has been replaced with IHostingEnvironment.

[Removing IApplicationEnvironment \ IRuntimeEnvironment](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/171)

```
public class Startup
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _appHost;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment appHost)
    {
        _appHost = appHost;
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
            .AddDbContext<MyContext>(
                options => { options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={_appHost.ContentRootPath}/data.db"); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Also check that the database file gets copied to the output directory when building (Right click "data.db" -> properties/Copy to Output Directory/copy always) if you want to deploy your local database to the server when publishing.

Answer (score 1):

you can set up the configuration adding;

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source = path//DatabaseName.db");
    }
```

the example uses SQLite, but you can choose your own DB.

Comment: They're not asking how to configure EF.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple DataContexts, the `EnsureCreated` method will only work on the first call. See its documentation:

> If the database exists and has any tables, then no action is taken

To create tables of additional DataContexts, use

```
 RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator = 
(RelationalDatabaseCreator) secondDbContext.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
databaseCreator.CreateTables();
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem and I found the answer in this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRmMYrSROPs
Just update your database via command:

> dotnet ef database update

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while, the error message is non contributory when the connection string is non-functional, leads you one down a few blind alleys. This conversation was immensely helpful. Seems in some way SQLite creates a temporary instance version which of course contains no tables and not the one you have interest in.

So check your connection string